# Angular.js geting data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have a problem with getting request in my api from Angular.js. After i loged in to my app I keep the username in $rootScope.currentuser,

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function () {
  if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
    app.isLoggedIn = true;
    Auth.getUser().then(function (data) {
      $rootScope.currentuser = data.data.username;
      app.username = data.data.username;
      app.useremail = data.data.email;
      app.loadme = true;
    });
  } else {
    app.isLoggedIn = false;
    app.username = '';
    $rootScope.currentuser = '';
    app.loadme = true;
  }
});
```

then I call the middleware:

```
$http.get('/api/costs/' + $rootScope.currentuser).then(function (data) {
  $scope.costs = data.data;
});
```

to get specific costs for current user, unfortunetelly this get request doesn't work, I checked $rootScope.currentuser right after login and this value is assigned properly. What is curious, when I manualy assigned in user name middleware

```
$http.get('/api/costs/' + 'test').then(function (data) {
  $scope.costs = data.data;
});
```

the date is populated.

Comment: add a console log right before the get request to check the `$rootScope.currentuser` value is assigned

Comment: I added console.log() and I cannot see any value assigned to $rootScope.currentuser. This is strange because I showing this value in the <h1> tag to checking this value and on the web page is correctly assigned.

Comment: @sachilaranawaka do you know how can I get this `$rootScope.currentuser` value, is there some better way to do this?

Comment: because at the time you send the request rootscope value is not assigned. make sure to call the http req after value assign to the rootscope

Comment: yes everything is ok, but after refreh the page, i got an error that `$rootScope.currentuser` is not assigned. How can I keep this value in this variable ?